# События на элементы загруженные с помощью Ajax

Tags: jquery, javascript

В jQuery есть функция .load()
она срабатывает по событию ready(), и на элементы загруженными с помощью ajax уже не распространяется(
есть еще выход из положения

```
$(document).on('название события','элемент', function(){
//здесь код
});
```

но там можно вставить `click`, `submit` и т.п.... все кроме `load`.
как решить проблему?
я нашел плагин к jQuery, который дает функцию код внутри которой срабатывает при загрузке элемента но опять же при onDomReady. пример:

```
$('img').bindImageLoad(function(){
alert('загрузилось!');
});
```

так вот к чему это: можно ли сделать конструкцию типа

```
$(document).on($('img').bindImageLoad(function(){
alert('загрузилось!');
});
});
```

Буду рад воспринять все варианты решения или предложения.

Comment: я не вам отвечал уже ? берешь все картинки в полученном элементы у которых property complete===false, и вешаешь на них one("load",function());, те которые уже complete сразу обрабатываешь

Comment: @eicto распешите пожалуйста конкретно что вы хотели сказать

Answer (score 1):

Может я неправильно понял....Вы хотите выполнить действия по завершению загрузки данных по ajax, например в div... Тогда получим:

```
$('#myDiv').load('ololo.com',function(e){

   //код...

})
```

Аналогично с $.post, $.get и $.ajax